# Handling session timeouts from AJAX requests

Tags: ajax, session, timeout

I need to able to handle session timeouts nicely from ajax requests. So the user's session has timeout and they should get redirected to the userlogin page if they submit an ajax request.

I just wondering is there anything in the platform that helps out. I want to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: I thought that happens automatically? https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/security_overview_sessions.htm

Answer (score 1):

That depends on where the AJAX is coming from. If you're in Visualforce code, you'll get a redirect to the login page, but if you're doing your own AJAX, you'll have to detect the INVALID_SESSION_ID error and perform whatever custom logic you'd like to do. Note that redirecting to a login page will cause your users to lose their view state, so be sure to save it so they can pick up where they left off.